# Server side processing table pagination - Datatable or any other?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am using datatable for my table. Since now there are lot of content in the table I have decided to make server side processing DataTable , following this link - https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

AJAX

```
{
  "draw": 2,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    [
      "Charde",
      "Marshall",
      "Regional Director",
      "San Francisco",
      "16th Oct 08",
      "$470,600"
    ],
    [
      "Colleen",
      "Hurst",
      "Javascript Developer",
      "San Francisco",
      "15th Sep 09",
      "$205,500"
    ]


  ]
...
    }
```

As shown above the table content is sent in an array format and used in JS.

Now I dont to use above way, since my table's `tr`/`td` have a lot of data-attributes and custom content,icons and many things its difficult to build the table in JS using AJAX data content.

I want to build the table content in the PHP itself (AJAX function) and send the full content to table because it will be easy for me to use the same old code to put in ajax function and use it.Basically I just want the server side pagination and whole table content to be build in AJAX php function.
  Can we do that in Datatable ?

Comment: Use  rendering callbacks to modify content any way you need. https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers There is nothing you can do in php html generation that can't be done client side...probably with less code

Comment: @charlietfl I am not saying that it cannot be done . I am just saying that if it is possible to get the whole HTML table content from AJAX PHP function. I want to use my old PHP code to build table content.

Comment: Sure but you wouldn't set up server side processing to do that. You would request the html, put it in page then initialize plugin. Is that what you want? Also isn't that what you were doing before? Am confused

Comment: @charlietfl yes if I click on page 2 in pagination it should request for table HTML content like <tr> td td </tr> and should update table automatically . I mean in ajax php function I will build the whole table content which includes all tr td data attribute, icons and everything. Am I clear enough ?

Comment: To be honest just defeating the server side processing concept that plugin uses. Cleaner to just set up rendering callbacks and use json. Really doubt it would take very long to set up the client side rendering callbacks